# Why is flextable suddenly throwing an error in R?

Tags: r, flextable

The flextable align() function is throwing this error:

Error in UseMethod("align") :
no applicable method for 'align' applied to an object of class "flextable"

It even occurs in the package example:

```
library(flextable)
ft <- flextable(head(mtcars)[,3:6])
ft <- align(ft, align = "right", part = "all")
ft
```

I'm using flextable 0.6.10 and R 4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have another package with a function named `align` loaded after flextable.  Can you try prefixing with `flextable::align` and see if the error goes away?

Comment: That must be what it is. I ran `flextable::align` and it worked. I'm using several packages associated with the `likert` package. I looked for an align function with all the packages and didn't get any hits, but one may have loaded something as a dependency.

Comment: likert has an align function https://github.com/jbryer/likert/blob/master/R/align.R